# how change empty result? mysql

Tags: mysql, isnull, ifnull

```
SELECT 'id'  FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 
(select min(`id`) FROM `table` where 
`id` < 1 and `ids` = 1)

id       ids
1         1
2         1
5         1
6         1
```

Result:

```
id = ''
```

I need to change `id=''` to `id='n/a'`

Answer (score 1):

If the query return a null result you can use COALESCE so :

```
SELECT COALESCE('id','N/A') FROM ...
```

OR if the return result is an empty string you can do :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN id = '' THEN 'N/A' ELSE id END FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be: [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)